# Discrete Math Injection and surjection of finite sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I really don't understand how to prove this. I guess I don't get how you can have a number go to an ordered pair. My problem is:

Suppose $U := \left\{0, 1, 2, 3\right\}$ and $W := \left\{(0, 0),(1, 0),(0, 1),(1, 1)\right\}$.
Prove that these sets are isomorphic by finding a bijection between them.

Comment: You can define your function one by one, it doesn't have to be a 'formula'.

Comment: Observe that $U$ and $W$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: Suppose you waned a bijection between $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\{w,x,y,z\}$.  There are $24$ bijections and any one of them will do.  Just write one down than then translate your original question into that choice

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides So I can just say f(U)=f(W) so then {(0,1,2,3)}={(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)}

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:U\to W$ Such that
$f(0)=(0,0)$
$f(1)=(1,0)$
$f(2)=(0.1)$
$f(3)=(1,1)$.

Thus it satisfies the properties of a bijection.
Also notice that this bijection need not to be unique. That means there can be more than one function that has got the bijective properties